# How to install freeimage.dll on Windows?

Tags: image

How to register/install freeimage.dll on my Windows XP machine? I have download the library and open my command shell pointing to the freeimage folder. I ran `regsvr32` but the library won't install .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy it to local or windows/system directory, only ActiveX and COM servers need regsvr32.

Comment: do i need to restart after copy. i copied it to my C:\Windows folder. I am on XP.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the library has dependencies not fullfilled.  try checking its dependencies using this tool: http://www.dependencywalker.com/
this software shows you all DLL's requiered by an EXE or DLL or OCX, if a dependency fails then regsvr32 fails to.
first check that all dependencies are fullfilled.

i think freeimage.dll is very old to be used on this days...maybe OS incompatibilities or a Service Pack update can cause a fail.